# Yii2 karthik editable column first row not working

Tags: yii2

I used karthik grid view and editable column to edit my grid view data. it not work for the first row of the grid view and work for the other rows when i enter value to the first row it give error like this

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

my gridview code is.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'pjax' => true,
            'pjaxSettings' => [
                    'options' => [
                        'id' => 'grid', 

                    ]
                    ],
            'export'=>false,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                [
                    'header'=>'Sub Category',
                    'value'=>'item.subCategory.name',
                ],
                'item.code',
                [
                    'header'=>'Brand',
                    'value'=>'item.brand.name',
                ],
                'item.description',
                'item.pack_size',
                [
                    'header'=>'Unit',
                    'value'=>'item.unit',
                ],
                [
                    'header'=>'Last Price',
                    'value'=>function($model){
                        $customerId = $model->customerOrderRequest->customer_id;
                        $lastPurchasedPrice = Item::getLastPurchasedPrice($customerId,$model->item_id);
                        return '$ ' . number_format($lastPurchasedPrice, 2);
                    }
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
                    'attribute'=>'qty', 
                    'editableOptions' => 
                    [
                      'formOptions' => ['action' => 'customer-order-request']
                    ],
                    'header' => 'Qty',
                ],
                [
                    'header'=>'Estimate',
                    'value'=>function($model)
                    {
                        return '123123.00';
                    }
                ],
                [
                    'header'=>'Price (UNIT)',
                    'format'=>'raw',
                    'value'=>function($modal){
                        $salse_rep_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_id;
                        $exsist_respond = Respond::find()->where(['sales_rep_id'=>$salse_rep_id,'customer_order_request_id'=>$modal->customer_order_request_id])->one();
                        if(!empty($exsist_respond)){
                            $exsist_respond_item = RespondItem::find()->where(['item_id'=>$modal->item_id,'respond_id'=>$exsist_respond->id])->one();
                            if(!empty($exsist_respond_item)){
                            $price = $exsist_respond_item->price;    
                            }  else {
                            $price = NULL;
                            }

                        }  else {
                            $price = NULL;
                        }
                        if(!empty($exsist_respond) && $exsist_respond->status !="Pending"){
                              return $price; 
                        }else{

                        return "<input type='text' class='respond-item' cor='$modal->customer_order_request_id' value='$price' item_id='$modal->item_id' />";

                        }

                        },
                    'visible'=>(Yii::$app->user->identity->ref_table =="sales_rep")? true:false
                ],


            ],
        ]); ?>
```

and my controller is

```
public function actionEditable()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) 
    {
        $customerItemsId = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
        print_r($customerItemsId);die();
        $model = RequestItem::findOne($customerItemsId);

        $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);

        $post = [];
        $posted = current($_POST['RequestItem']);
        $post['RequestItem'] = $posted;

        if ($model->load($post)) 
        {

            $model->save();
            $output = '';

            $out = Json::encode(['output'=>$output, 'message'=>'']);
        } 
        echo $out;
        return;
    }

}
```

any one can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Form tag nested.**

a trick: Add a fake form to let browser remove it.

I meet this problem today, cause I put a form in another, they are nested.
So the browser remove the first nested form.

In the official W3C XHTML specification, Section B. "Element Prohibitions", states that:

> "form must not contain other form elements."

[official website](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

Following is sample code:

```html
       <form id="thisisMainForm">
          <form id="dummy"> ->This will get Removed
                <gridview id="thisisEditableGridView">
                      Gridviewcode.....
                </gridview>
          </form>        
       </form>
```

Comment: This was absolutely correct. I can give only one up but this deserves 100 up votes :-) I have edited the answer with a sample code